# Eventhandler does not fire

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class which performs an async operation.
While that async operation (which works downloads a file) it should show a new dialog.

To close that dialog again and also show a progress in it, I made events that are fired and should let the event handlers do actions.

To show you that a bit clearer:

```
var dialog = new DownloadDialog();
DoAsyncDownload();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   dialog.Close();
   // Go on
}
```

So the download dialog is just there to show the user that a download is going on.
In order to show a progress and close the dialog then again, I want to work event-based.
What I made is an event:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DownloadFinished();

protected virtual void OnDownloadFinished(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DownloadFinished != null) DownloadFinished(sender, e);
}
```

Well, so in the method that is called async I call it like that, when the file is downloaded:

```
OnDownloadFinished();
```

Then this event is fired.
So, in order to make the dialog receieve this event I set an handler with the correct signature in the dialog's class.

Then I set this handler like that:

```
this.DownloadFinished += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(dialog.DownloadFinishedHandler);
```

But the event handler does never execute its code. :(
I checked this with breakpoints.

I think the problem is using a webclient to download the file. Its eventhandlers are not set at the right time I think.

The webclient is declared as a member outside any functions or anything, so that every function can access it.

Then the code in the method that is called async looks like that:

```
packageDownloader.DownloadFile(MyUrl, "Url");   
OnPackageDownloadFinished(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Like I already said above, this functions is called then.
The same problem is appearing with the progress changed, it is the same.

The thing I am sure that there is any way this would work or the webclient is the guilty guy, is that I have already done the same thing with another method and there the eventhandlers are called and everything works fine. So in this other method another thing is done, but after that it also raises an event. And the handler set is exactly the same.

Only here it doesn't work, I think it is the webclient.

PS: If you have any questions or something isn't clear to you, ask me. ;)

Comment: "Its eventhandlers are not set at the right time I think." It's easy to find out. As you said - check it with breakpoints. Put a breakpoint where you add your handler to the event, and put a breakpoint inside the *OnDownloadFinished* method. This way you will see which breakpoint will be hit first, and whether it is in the desired order...

Comment: Why aren't you using `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx

Comment: Well, I made it, it first hits the point where the eventhandler's added.
@YuvalItzchakov Ok, I will do this later, you're right, but in general, I need to fix this problem, that is the point.
I also set the ProgressChanged-event for the progress, but even that does not fire.

Comment: Okay, then it is really confusing to me why you said that the eventhandlers are not set at the right time...

Comment: I thought, that I maybe had to set them in any other event.

Comment: Are you by any chance in your code remove the DownloadFinishedHandler event handler again? If so, it might happen (right) before the event is being raised.

Comment: Yes, I do, but only after the dialog is closed, and as it is shown modal, it blocks the thread, so no, it can't be removing it before the event is raised. Also checked that just now.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it is not really possible to deduce the relevant flow of your code from your question, except that there is an issue with the added eventhandler(s) (as you already stated). I would suggest to debug a little more regarding adding and removing of event handlers, invocations of the *OnDownloadFinished* method (which will raise the event) as well as invocations of the event handlers you added. Something is not working as you expect and you have to find out...

Comment: Ok, I will try and report the problem as soon as I will (hopefully) find it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was very dumb. I didn't download the file asnyc, so no events could be raised that clear way.